# Calculations in AWK

Tags: awk

I need to perform calculations in awk. For each array[$1,$2] i need to check $3. If it is "5310" the value in $4 is positiv, else the value is negativ.
In the end I need to substract all negativ values from the positiv values per `array[$1,$2]`

input

```
K019001^ABC^531^12   
K019001^ABC^601^12  
K019002^ABC^531^100  
K019002^ABC^601^40  
K019003^ABC^531^50  
K019003^ABC^601^30  
K019003^ABC^601^40  
K019004^ABC^531^10
```

desired output

```
K019001^ABC^0  
K019002^ABC^60  
K019003^ABC^-20  
K019004^ABC^10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your question mentions `"5310"`; your data shows `531` and `601`. Please be careful. Also, we prefer to help people fix their honest attempt at resolving the problem, rather than us writing the code for you in its entirety.

Answer (score 4):

Use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=SUBSEP="^"} {a[$1,$2] += $4 * ($3==531 ? 1 : -1)}
```

END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file

```
K019001^ABC^0
K019004^ABC^10
K019002^ABC^60
K019003^ABC^-20
```

**UPDATE:: To get correct ordering:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="^"} {k=$1 FS $2; if (!a[k]) b[c++]=k} $3==531{a[k]+=$4; next} {a[k]-=$4}
        END {for (i=0; i<length(b); i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file

K019001^ABC^0
K019002^ABC^60
K019003^ABC^-20
K019004^ABC^10
```

Comment: If you also set `SUBSEP="^"` in the BEGIN block, you don't need to build `k` -- you would use `a[$1,$2]`: `BEGIN {FS=OFS=SUBSEP="^"} {a[$1,$2] += $4 * ($3==531 ? 1 : -1)}`

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks. Yes you're always correct :P. Let me edit.